# SP2013Online: How create a custom dashboard with indicators and progressbars like this example?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, office-365

We have a old SharePoint 2007 intranet. On this intranet we have a list with some columns like "name, fte, available, unit, contract enddate, expecting enddate etc". Some of these columns are showed as indicators and progressbar. This maded custom in a content query webpart with a custom itemstyle.xsl.

Now we have a new SharePoint online 2013 intranet (office 365). I would like to create the same dashboard. I have already created the list with the same columns. What is the best method to show indicators and progressbars for a custom list in SharePoint 2013 Online (o365)?

ps. the indicators are colored red when the date is past and green when it is in the future. This is not a visual studio solution!

[image]

Comment: I would go for JSLink on the view :)

Comment: Thanks, I have googled on JSLink and this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which level of O365 you are using and my understanding is that you do not want a custom code solution. I would recommend using Business Intelligence to drive your metric icons and progress bars. [Here is a link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/Products/SharePoint.aspx).

Alternatively, I would look into using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) to enhance your dashboard with dynamically driven content.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Robert Lindgren was the right one. With the JSLink method it is possible to implement some logic to show a image instead of a date or number.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find on my blog several examples that show how to create progress bars using calculated columns:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/?s=progress&submit=Search

To convert the calculated column into actual HTML, in SP 2013 you can use this JSlink method:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2013/06/19/html-calculated-column-client-side-rendering/

The same technique can be used for other types of indicators, see my blog for more examples.